# Embedding URL for each datapoint in a plotly scattergeo plot in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: hyperlink, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I'm creating a map of radio stations using plotly in Jupyter notebook. My goal is to be able to export it as an html file, which will then be embedded on a website. The example below (plots points, saves .html file) is pretty similar to what I have so far.

I would like to embed hyperlinks for each of the points, either in the hovertext or over the points themselves, and have these links persist when the graph is saved as an html file. Can this be done?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_february_us_airport_traffic.csv')
df['text'] = df['airport'] + '' + df['city'] + ', ' + df['state'] + '' + 'Arrivals: ' + df['cnt'].astype(str)

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scattergeo(
        lon = df['long'],
        lat = df['lat'],
        text = df['text'],
        mode = 'markers',
        marker_color = df['cnt'],
        ))

fig.update_layout(
        title = 'Most trafficked US airports<br>(Hover for airport names)',
        geo_scope='usa',
    )
fig.show()
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='examplemap.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Making some progress...

Add `import plotly.graph_objects as go` to the preamble, then add:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(
    lat=[40.678306],
    lon=[-105.040889],
    marker={
        "color": ["Crimson"],
        "line": {
            "width": 1
        },
        "size": 10
    },
    mode="markers+text",
    name="",
    text=[ "<a href=\"https://www.nist.gov/pml/time-and-frequency-division/radio-stations/wwv/\">WWV</a>"],
    textfont={
        "color": ["Crimson"],
        "family": ["Droid Sans, sans-serif"],
        "size": [22]
    },
    textposition=["top center"]
))
```

Still have to get this integrated into a for loop, but it does generate links and export effectively to HTML.